# How to make session/cookies work in all subdomains in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have several subdomains like 'a.domain.com','b.domain.com' but I found that if i login at subdomain a, session/cookies won't work in b, and i have to login again in 'b.domain.com'

How do I make login session work in all subdomains?

**Update:**

I found each subdomain has a different session id...

**Update:**

I found I could only login in several domians like 'bench' and 'post', but cannot login in 'book' and other domains. Really strange.

Comment: did you have a look here: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/7861-sessions-and-subdomains ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use PHP's session.cookie_domain value and set it to your top level domain (.domain.com). By editing php.ini or setting using ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain.com');

Good luck :)
Shai.

Comment: Well, after I changed that setting I can't even login... By the way, I use database to store session, if that cares.

Comment: To store the session? what do you mean? Maybe you changed it incorrectly, it should do the job. Can you paste in the line you added and where exactly? Shai.

Answer (score 8):

You could set it in yii **config/main.php** file, like i did. (*i'm not sure if you still have to change php.ini file, but i would say "no", because this configuration below fixed my problem*).

**protected/config/main.php**

```
...
'components' => array( 
    ...        
    'user'=>array(
        ...    
        'identityCookie' => array('domain' => '.mydomain.com', //note dot before domain name 
        // identityCookie same as "session->cookieParams->domain"
    ),
    'session' => array(
        'autoStart'=>true,
        'cookieParams' => array('domain' => '.mydomain.com'),
    ),
    ...
)
...
```